# Why is the string value null when passed from activity to broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am passing a value from activity to broadcast receiver:

My activity code:

```
String stringBuilder = "Hello";
String phone_no = "1234567890";

try{
     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

     sms.sendTextMessage(phone_no, null, stringBuilder, null, null);

     Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(contacts.this, Receiver.class);

     broadcastIntent.putExtra("message",stringBuilder);

     sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

 }catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

My broadcast receiver code:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         //String msg= intent.getStringExtra("message") //returns null

         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

         if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {

             String msg= intent.getStringExtra("message") //returns null

             if (bundle != null){

                  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                  if (pdus.length == 0) {
                    return;
                  }

                  // large message might be broken into many
                  SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                  for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                      messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                      sb.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                  }
                  String sender = messages[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                  String message = sb.toString();
                  
                if (message.equals(msg)) {
                    //do something
                }

              }
   
             Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //empty toast
    }
}
```

This is my manifest:

```
         <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

As you can see the `key` is same in both the cases, still the value is returned null in my broadcast receiver, when passed from the activity. I've run out of ideas on how to pass the value from activity to broadcast receiver. Please help me.

I just want to check if the message received in my broadcast receiver (`String message = sb.toString();`) is equal to the message sent from the activity (`stringBuilder`).

Comment: Is your Receiver running in a separate process from the one that has the Activity broadcasting that intent?

Comment: Yes I have created a separate Broadcast Receiver class `Receiver.class` and I've also registered it in the manifest

Comment: A different class *does not necessarily* mean a separate process. You should confirm that. If your manifest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67520738/timeline#history_eaa1ad6e-e321-40bd-9b7a-2bc90415a9d2) is anything to go by, I suspect they are all in the same process, in which case, Intents are a bad design for inter-component communication.

Comment: Are you sure that your data is a String and not just a CharSequence? You may be calling `putExtra(String name, CharSequence value)` instead of `putExtra(String name, String value)`. If so, then `getStringExtra()` won't find a string and will return null.

Comment: But `stringBuilder` is a string

Comment: The intent action must use the app package name with a unique identifier. Could you try: broadcastIntent.setAction(getPackageName() + ".CUSTOM_INTENT");

Comment: OK. I thought that you might have simplified the code for the question and used a string instead of a CharSequence that may be in the actual code.

Comment: Tried it @davisjp, still doesn't work

Comment: `getPackageName()+".android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"` is not equal to `"android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`

Comment: I have already provided the `action` in my manifest, so the intent can fetch the action. The problem is that it can't fetch the string value that I attached using `putExtra()`

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve?  Do you just want to send an intent to a receiver within your app or do you specifically want to send the `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` action containing Intent which is a protected broadcast?

Comment: Also, what's the Android version that your app targets?

Comment: I am just making an app which sends an sms , and in the broadcast receiver it checks if the received sms is equal to the sent sms ( `stringBuilder`). It targets sdk 29

Comment: @Abhishek In that case, have you tried using a different Intent action and testing the same code. You shouldn't be trying to piggyback on a protected intent and change the values of extras that intent carries.  That intent is supposed to carry PDUs. Your doesn't.

Comment: I've updated my code, please take a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232509/discussion-between-abhishek-and-zoso).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looking at your code one more time, I noticed a fishy line that might causes the problem.

```
broadcastIntent.putExtra("message",stringBuilder);
```

Did you mean, to use it like this:

```
broadcastIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,stringBuilder);
```

Then you can get it by:

```
intent.getStringExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
```

Or if want to send multiple stuff:

```
broadcastIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, new String[] { stringBuilder, phone_no } );
```

To get them:

```
String[] str = intent.getStringArrayExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
String message = str[0];
String phone_no = str[1];
```

Or you can use a `Bundle` as well.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putCharSequence("message", stringBuilder);
bundle.putCharSequence("phone_no", phone_no); 
broadcastIntent.putExtras(bundle);
```

Later you can retrive them using following method:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))
        {
            //String message= intent.getStringExtra("message") //returns null
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null) {
                String message = bundle.getString("message");
                Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                 Toast.makeText(context,"Bundle is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it using `Bundle` too, still it doesn't work. I think this is a bug in android atudio

Answer (score 0):

> Why am I receiving an empty toast?

Your `stringBuilder` variable - which you did not include in your code - is null.

Comment: It's not null, I've checked it in the activity, but when I pass it to the broadcast receiver class, it shows to be null.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing 2 different things. You have your `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest to be triggered by incoming SMS. When this happens your `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` will be called with an `Intent` that contains `ACTION="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"`. This broadcast `Intent` is sent by the Android framework and will not contain your "extras".

You also have an `Activity` which is sending a broadcast `Intent` to your `BroadcastReceiver`. In this case, the `Intent` contains your "extras" but no ACTION, so it will not enter your `if` block.

Comment: So how do I fetch the value in my broad cast receiver class?

Comment: Just move the `getStringExtra()` outside of the `if` block.

Comment: Is your `BroadcastReceiver` being triggered by your `Activity` or by an incoming SMS? If it is triggered by an incoming SMS, it will not contain your "extras".

Comment: It's triggered by an incoming sms

Comment: Assuming that the broadcaster has the correct permissions, the intent shall carry the same extras as the broadcaster added. There's no _resetting_ of extras per see. The OP indeed seems to be mixing up two thing by using the same `SMS_RECEIVED` action.

Comment: You will not get your "extras" in the `Intent` that is triggered by incoming SMS. This `Intent` is sent by the Android framework, not by your code. You have no control over what is in that `Intent`. There are "extras" in that `Intent` and they are defined in the documentation. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the pending intent to the function :

```
 private fun sendSms(num : String , sms : String){
    try {
        val smsManager: SmsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        
        val intent = Intent(this , SendBroadCast::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("sms", "Send to $num")
        val sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 47, intent ,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val intent1 = Intent(this , DeliveredBroadcast::class.java)
        intent1.putExtra("sms", "Delivered to $num")
        val deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 47, intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(num, null, sms, sentIntent, deliveredIntent)
        
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ex.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
 }
```

and for each pending intent you need to create an object of the broadcast receiver class,

to listen to send message :

```
class SendBroadCast: BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Toast.makeText(context, intent?.extras?.getString("sms").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
}
```

and for hearing delivery message

```
class DeliveredBroadcast : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Toast.makeText(context, intent?.extras?.getString("sms").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   }
}
```

and don't forget to declare your broadcast receiver in the file manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".SendBroadCast"/>
 <receiver android:name=".DeliveredBroadcast"/>
```

in my case, as I use SMS manager, I need to add permission to the file manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```