# CountDownTimer in Android doesn't work properly

Tags: android, countdowntimer

the count down timer sometimes entering the onFinish() method although the time haven't run out

At least i think its the timer, coz there is no other place that the intent can switch over except the onClick() method but the bug is when the user doesn't do anything

sometimes it running as it should be but it randomly appear again, and i cant trust this bug not coming again when a user tries to play the game

here is the code

```
public void timer(int time2) {

        if (time2==-1)//if the user set no time limit
        {
            cdt.cancel();
        }
        cdt= new CountDownTimer(timeleft, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timeleft=millisUntilFinished;
                updatetime();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                cdt.cancel();
                finished();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void finished() {
        Intent goGameOver=new Intent(this, GameOver.class);
        boolean end=true;
        goGameOver.putExtra("ENDS",end);
        startActivity(goGameOver);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried rxJava?

Comment: @kamal Nayan what is rxjava

Comment: https://www.programmersought.com/article/8407870662/

Comment: Read here about RxJava -> https://factoryhr.medium.com/understanding-java-rxjava-for-beginners-5eacb8de12ca

Comment: Why not just put a `if else` statement in `onTick`? e.g. `if(millisUntilFinished > 0) {...} else {...}`

Comment: could you please explain what you want to do using countdown. i found a logical mistake in it. like onTick method after finish you will have 0 value in timeleft variable. next time you init your countdown with timeleft variable it will execute finish instantly.

Comment: @Darkman thanks you, i will use this, i cant know for sure if it solves the problem but at least i would know that the timer has nothing to do with it :)

Comment: @MuhammadAli i'm making a quiz so i dont really need to use the timer once more

Comment: @CoffeeGod42 Even how you're passing data between intents is incorrect. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67563823/10534012)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that whenever you start a new timer the old timer still runs, which is causing the illusion that the timer has somehow reached the `onFinish()` method, when in reality the old timer reached the time limit, therefore, entering the `onFinish()` method.

<sub>*Added on behalf of question author.*</sub>